# How to pass a text box value from one html page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to pass a textbox value from one html page to another html page and print on the second page. I have page1.html and page2.html. I dont want to use asp or php any server side scripting language simply i want to do using javascript or jquery anyone which is easy.

```html
<script>
        function checkPassword() {
            if (document.getElementById("name").value == "") {
                document.getElementById("studname").innerHTML = "Enter your name. Field cannot be left blank.";
                alert('Enter your name.');
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("class").value == "select") {
                document.getElementById("classname").innerHTML = "Select your class.";
                alert('Select your class.');
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("section").value == "select") {
                document.getElementById("secname").innerHTML = "Select your section.";
                alert('Select your section.');
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("password").value == "") {
                document.getElementById("passwordname").innerHTML = "Enter your password.";
                alert('Enter your password.');
                return false;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('password').value == '12345' && document.getElementById("class").value == 'V' && document.getElementById("section").value == 'a') {
                location.href = 'Start.html?name=' + document.getElementById('name').value + '?class=' + document.getElementById('class').value;
            } 
            else {
                alert('Your Class, Section and Password doesn\'t match. Please re-enter correctly.');
                return false;
            }
        }
      </script>
```

Comment: Query string, LocalStorage. ?

Answer (score 0):

Run this code, u ll get the output what u needed.

html1.html

```
 <html>
<form type=get action="html2.html">
<table>
<tr>
<td>First Name:</td>
<td><input type=text name=firstname size=10></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name:</td>
<td><input type=text name=lastname size=10></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Age:</td>
<td><input type=text name=age size=10></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2><input type=submit value="Submit">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

html2.html

```
<html>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function getParams(){
var idx = document.URL.indexOf('?');
var params = new Array();
if (idx != -1) {
var pairs = document.URL.substring(idx+1, document.URL.length).split('&');
for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
nameVal = pairs[i].split('=');
params[nameVal[0]] = nameVal[1];
}
}
return params;
}
params = getParams();
firstname = unescape(params["firstname"]);
lastname = unescape(params["lastname"]);
age = unescape(params["age"]);
document.write("firstname = " + firstname + "<br>");
document.write("lastname = " + lastname + "<br>");
document.write("age = " + age + "<br>");
</script>
</html>
```